# Not sure how to use reportScores:withCompletionHandler: (Crashes)

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm using this method:

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) category
{
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:category forPlayer:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID];
scoreReporter.value = score;
scoreReporter.context = 0;
NSNumber *scoreToReport = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:score];

[GKScore reportScores:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scoreToReport] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
}];
}
```

to report scores to game center (have already made leaderboard in itunes connect and so), but this error pops when it gets to reportScores method: -[__NSCFNumber leaderboardIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

What can it be? Thanks!

(There's quite a specific reason I use this method and not reportScoreWithCompletionIdentifier but AFAIK I can't tell it because of the NDA, but anyway is this the right way to use that class method?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GKScore [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> ```
> + (void)reportScores:(NSArray *)scores withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
> scores
> An array of score objects to report to Game Center.

Note that it says "array of **score objects**", not "array of NSNumbers". In other words, your array must contain GKScore objects, not NSNumbers.